# Best way to define an Image variable in racket

Tags: racket

Both, the official racket tutorial and the book, "Realm of Racket" suggest using Dr. Racket to load and define images in Racket.

I however am using Geiser (racket-repl) with Emacs. I define images using the

```
(make-object bitmap% (image-location))
```

function.

Is this the best way to load an image? Or are there more efficient and easy ways?
I ask because I was confronted with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894875/overlapping-module-imports-in-racket).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are already using the `2htdp/image` library (which your other SO post suggests), then you may wish to use the `bitmap` function from the same library. See [this section](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html?q=2htdp/image#%28part._.Bitmaps%29) of the documentation for `2htdp/image`.

You can use it like this:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image)
(define my-image (bitmap "path/to/image.png"))
```